# unknown public key 8F0871F202119294 on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux

I already got this installed:

```
1 core/archlinux-keyring 20170104-1 [installed]
10 blackarch/blackarch-keyring 20140118-3 [installed]
```

But I get an error when upgrading `libc++abi` from AUR:

```
==> Verifying source file signatures with gpg...
    llvm-3.9.1.src.tar.xz ... FAILED (unknown public key 8F0871F202119294)
    libcxx-3.9.1.src.tar.xz ... FAILED (unknown public key 8F0871F202119294)
    libcxxabi-3.9.1.src.tar.xz ... FAILED (unknown public key 8F0871F202119294)
==> ERROR: One or more PGP signatures could not be verified!
==> ERROR: Makepkg was unable to build libc++.
==> Restart building libc++abi ? [y/N]
```

How to resolve this? Is there a way to know which keyring I should install to solve this issue?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Keys from AUR are not in the keyrings provided by the distributions' repositories.

You will need to find and add the AUR package/upstream keys manually, if you trust them.

Start by checking the `PKGBUILD` file of the package, then the comments in the AUR to see where/if to get and add the keys.

Answer (score 73):

`gpg --recv-keys 8F0871F202119294` (AUR)

- the missing key needs to be added to your `USER` keyring

I did not need to trust the key for `makepkg` to finish the build.

- `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` also needed:

`keyserver-options no-honor-keyserver-url`

in my particular case

---

- Missing keys for official Arch repos are normally missing an updated
  `archlinux-keyring`

Comment: I was so proud of myself for remembering the command `pacman-key --recv-keys KEY`, and so sad when it didn't work. I see that it's my user keyring that needs adjusting, not the pacman keyring. Thanks!

Comment: i also needed to create that conf file and add that line

Comment: and i had to download and import their public key

Answer (score -1):

Try: `sudo pacman -U /path/to/file.tar.xz`

Do that for all of the file types, then try your upgrade again.